# How to add noise to a random variable whose range is the unit interval?

Tags: distributions, error, beta-distribution, noise

I have a list of values sampled from a beta distribution that therefore lie in the interval [0,1]. I would like to add (e.g. Gaussian) noise to these values, but of course there is the problem of the values then potentially leaving the interval. What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Could you explain the purpose of this "noise" and what it represents?  After all, as a purely *mathematical* question this has infinitely many equally good answers, but as a *statistical* question the answers have to reflect the reality you are attempting to model.  What is the genesis of this noise and why do you need to incorporate it explicitly in a distribution? Indeed, what role will this distribution play in your study?

Comment: Thanks for your question. I am simulating an experiment and then running a method on the results of that experiment. My method relies on estimating some hidden value $d$ that ranges from 0 to 1. From the simulated data, I know what the true value of $d$ is, but in practice, I will need to approximate $d$. Therefore, I would like to add noise to the simulated values of $d$ at increasing levels to see what influence this noise has on the ability of my method.

Comment: Ordinarily one would begin by considering how the experimental outcomes could deviate from $d$ and go on from there to create a probability model of those deviations. Without any further information about your experiment there is little we could add to that. What does all this have to do with the beta distribution you mention, given that there is a single "true value" of $d$?

Comment: There are thousands of $d$s that I generate from a beta distribution - probably the distribution isn't entirely relevant, it could equally be a uniform distribution.

Comment: I'm not really sure how I can use your advice. I have residuals from predicted and true values of $d$ that appear to follow a normal distribution. But if I add normal noise, I get the same problem described in OP.

Comment: I suspect I don't fully understand. At this point it seems to me that in each iteration of the simulation you choose a $d$ randomly and then, *conditional on that value,* you create some experimental data and apply your method to those.  If this is a correct interpretation, then the issue concerns how to generate the experimental data--you definitely would not want just to add noise to $d$!

Comment: You misunderstand. I have a vector $\vec d$ with each $d_i \in [0,1]$. These are the true values and they are fixed. In an experimental setting, I wish to estimate these, and depending on how good my estimator is, they will be either close or far away to the true values of $\vec d$. In simulation, I know what these values are in advance, and I have no real means of pretending to estimate them. When I use the true values of $\vec d$, my method works extremely well. I want to add a little noise to see how much it degrades my method. Then add more noise and see how much worse it gets.

Comment: Could you please clarify your question by editing the text of the question?

Comment: Against closing: It's often useful to test an estimator using simulated data, but in the real world, noise is often normally distributed.  So a reasonable way to investigate the quality of an estimator using simulated data is to add normally distributed noise to underlying values (which will be generated randomly--how isn't that important).  However, the data is constrained to an interval, and the normal distribution isn't.  The question doesn't have the specificity that would come from using real data, but still seems appropriate to me.  I'm grateful for the answers given, in fact.

Comment: Would it make the question more acceptable if, instead of asking "What is the proper way to do this?", OP had instead said, "What are some ways do this?  What are their advantages and disadvantages?  Under what circumstances would each be appropriate?"  (And what if OP didn't know enough to ask the question in that way, as the existing wording suggests?  Might it be reasonable to provide such answers?)

Comment: @Mars This thread was closed because serious questions were raised about what it is asking and they were not addressed.  The closure is unrelated to any inherent interest in the question or its appropriateness on this site.  It is also unrelated to the quality of any answers that might have appeared.  Letting ambiguous questions stand is dangerous, because different readers may interpret them in wildly different ways, causing the answers to range from helpful to useless to actively wrong.  If a particular interpretation interests you, why not ask a clear question of your own?

Comment: Thanks @whuber, I'll consider that.  I do see that OP never clarified.  Fine lines can't be avoided.  I had originally formulated a question, but a link to this popped up, and I considered it near enough that I felt mine would be a duplicate.  If I ask, it would only be for the sake of a somewhat clearer formulation of a very general question in order to solicit additional answers similar to (though maybe more detailed than) those given to this one.

Answer (score 12):

A traditional way to handle constrained variables is to transform them into unconstrained variables, apply the jittering, and turn them back into the original scale.

For instance, if $d_i\in(0,1)$, one can use the logit transform
$$x_i=\text{logit}(d_i)=\log\left(\frac{d_i}{1-d_i}\right)$$
and add as much noise as necessary$$y_i=x_i+\epsilon_i$$ where $\epsilon_i$ is for instance a centred Gaussian variate, before returning
$$\delta_i=\exp(y_i)\big/(1+\exp(y_i))=1\big/(1+\exp(-y_i))$$

Here is an illustration in R:

```
> d=rbeta(10^4,2.4,6.2)
> logit=function(x){log(x/(1-x))}
> de=1/(1+exp(-rnorm(10^4,mean=logit(d),sd=2)))
```

Answer (score 8):

It appears there are many ways to accomplish what you are looking for. Here's one suggestion.

Treat each $d$ as if it were the value of some function $\Phi$ from the real number line to the unit interval. For example, let $\Phi$ denote the cumulative density function of the standard normal distribution, so that $d = \Phi(z)$ for some real-valued $z$. Then $z = Probit(d)$, where $Probit$ denotes the inverse of $\Phi$. Let $\hat{z} = z + a \cdot e$, where $e$ is a standard normal random variable and $a >0$ is a scaling factor. Let $\hat{d} = \Phi(\hat{z})$ be your noisy estimate of $d$. Putting everything together, you have

$\hat{d} = \Phi(Probit(d) + a \cdot e)$

which will lie in the open unit interval. By adjusting $a$ you adjust the degree of noise.